# How to change facet_wrap titles' colours?

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
df<-data.frame(c(1:5,11:15),c(1:10),c(1,1,1,1,1,2,1,2,1,2),c(rep('o',5),rep('m',5)))
colnames(df)<-c('a','b','c','d')
qplot(a,b,data=df,geom = 'point',color=factor(df$c))+facet_wrap(~d)+scale_colour_manual(values=c("blue","orange"))+theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill='white', colour='black'))
```

With the code above, the facet titles' backgrounds are grey. How to change it into white in order to fit the whole plot?

Comment: Did you try 'theme(strip.background = ...)`?

Comment: Or perhaps `+ theme_bw()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this with `+theme(panel.background=element_rect(fill='white', colour='black'),strip.background=element_rect(fill='white', colour='white'))`